# I have to create canvas map

Tags: wordpress, canvas

I have to create a map based on MySQL database data.
Please find [URL here](https://rentals.loftey.com/?utm_expid=.qppWTChgSRaawxtk4yO5xw.0&utm_referrer=). Map will show only desktop version.

If anyone knows please help me.

Thanks